# Count features within a convex_hull polygon

Tags: qgis, labeling, geometry-generator

I have a point geometry layer with which I have built an expression that creates a convex_hull for the features closest to the features that have a given value:

```
convex_hull( 
    collect(
        $geometry,
        group_by:=overlay_nearest(
            'PT',
            $id,
            "idff" = 1
        )
    )
)
```

I get this satisfying result:

[image]

Now I am trying to calculate the number of points that are part of each convex_hull (including those with value 1 and value 2), with the goal of labeling the centroid of each convex_hull with this calculation. For this I am trying to develop an expression in this sense, but as you will see at the moment it is not working.

What corrections or new approach should I give to this expression?

And how could I calculate the value expressed in percentage?

```
aggregate(
    layer:='PT', 
    aggregate:='count', 
    expression:=within(
        $geometry, 
        geometry(@parent)
    ),
    filter:=overlay_nearest(
        'PT',
        $id,
        "idff" = 1
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
with_variable(
    'ch',
    convex_hull(
        collect(
            $geometry,
            group_by:=overlay_nearest(
                'PT',
                $id,
                "idff" = 1
            )
        )
    ),
    aggregate(
        'PT',
        'count',
        1,
        within($geometry, @ch) or intersects($geometry, @ch)
    )
)
```